# Provide response to prompt in Shell when mapping network drive

Tags: windows, shell

I want to map a drive in one line in shell

I tried:

```
net use W: \\network\drive
```

However I'm getting the response

```
W: has a remembered connection to \\network\drive. Do you want to overwrite the remembered connection? (Y/N) [Y]:
```

(However if I try to run `W:` I get `The system cannot find the drive specified`.

I also tried

```
net use W: \\network\drive & echo Y
```

But same response.

How can I send `Y` and hit ENTER so that it finishes mapping the drive?

Comment: On my computer it does not prompt. I just get System Error 85. Is there something you aren't saying?

Comment: I'm trying to run this through an an Airflow ssh connection.

Comment: As your code stands it works. Example `net use h: \\127.0.0.1\C$\Windows` run this multiple times as administrator (as C$ is a standard hidden admin share).

Comment: Have you tried `net use W: /delete` before mapping?

Comment: I'm having the same issue here. I was previously able to use `cd /s` to switch to my network drive but that has stopped working. Upon using `net use S: \\network\drive`, I get prompted but have no opportunity to respond before "No valid response was provided" is returned. This is all happening within the Mingw64 shell provided with Git Bash.

Comment: @Spedwards - Did you try `net use S: /delete` before the drive mapping? –
When required drive is not mapped the prompt `Do you want to overwrite the remembered connection? (Y/N)` shouldn't appear.

Comment: @Jackdaw The prompt does appear and the same thing happens, I get no chance to respond. The only reason I'm trying to remap is because I can no longer `cd` to the drive in Shell for some reason.

Comment: @Spedwards - Try to use with option `/yes`: `NET USE S: \\network\drive /YES`.
Or if it is acceptable remove all drives mapping by using NET USE * /DELETE /YES and then start to map all network drives.

Comment: @Jackdaw Neither of those worked (it didn't like the `/yes`), but I thought I'd try and see if I could `cd` directly to the network share (`cd \\network\drive`) and it gave me a clue by saying: `bash: cd: \networkdrive: No such file or directory`. I tried `net use S: \\\\network\\drive` and it worked. I have no idea when this started happening but it feels good to figure out.

Comment: Is this [tag:cmd] or [tag:powershell]? Can someone update the tags?

Comment: @kvantour I updated the tags already. It's shell. Not cmd or powershell.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to add /Y or /YES to your net.exe commandline so it will autamatically answer all user input with yes. Like this:

```
net use W: \\network\drive /Y
```