# Error: The system cannot find the drive specified (while accessing a mapped drive remotely) using winrs

Tags: windows, remote-access, mapped-drive

I am running the following command using machine1 (in administrator mode):

```
winrs -r:machine2 "net use U: \\\\bosln0\\sore45 /persistent:yes & cd U:\ples\prefile\filesreg & echo abc"
```

I am getting error:

```
U: has a remembered connection to \\bosln0\sore45. Do you
want to overwrite the remembered connection? (Y/N) [Y]: No valid response was provided.

**The system cannot find the drive specified.**
abc
```

But, when i am using command:

```
winrs -r:machine2 "cd C:\ples\prefile\filesreg & echo abc"
```

No issue is coming.

Why is issue coming only with mapped network drives? How can I resolve the issue?

Note: Command is running from machine1 in administrator mode.

Comment: Add /Y to your NET USE command to auto say YES to all user input. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55940457/provide-response-to-prompt-in-shell-when-mapping-network-drive

Comment: @Poiter, tried adding Yes, still issue is coming.

Comment: Remove the existing mapping